# Is Star Trek Picard's opening theme music in any way inspired by Caprica's opening theme music?

Tags: soundtrack, genre-characteristics

*Star Trek: Picard's* opening theme music is one of prettiest themes I have heard in long time, but I realized that the first part (first 18 seconds) of it, sounded very familiar...

It took me a while to figure out what it reminded me of, which was the opening theme (and renditions in the season 1 soundtrack) of *Caprica* (from about 8 seconds to 24 seconds).

While I know that Jeff Russo created the theme music and score for *Star Trek: Picard* and that Bear McCreary created the theme music and score for *Caprica*, I find the coincidence a little more than that, because both series (so far) happen to be conspiracies centered around the rise and/or fear of artificial intelligence in the form of humanoid androids!

So my question is, *was Jeff Russo inspired by or intentionally referencing *Carprica* theme music in his for *Star Trek: Picard* or are these common genre characteristics in sci-fi TV/Movie score?*

Comment: Well, I'm not the only one who noticed the flute (or piccolo?) part(s) being similar (family, friends). It's only 20 seconds of music, but they have similar instruments (in that part) and conjure up the same sorrowful feelings. But if that is the community's consensus, that's fine.

Comment: First of all: When I have learnt correctly from this SE  your  question is for SE music fan and doesn’t belong to this place here. Now to answer your question: only because both use the piccolo there is no similarity among these two pieces, or you can many other music like e.g. the intro pf Aquarius by 5th Dimension or the opening bars of Lohengrin by Wagner etc.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Like I said, if it's too off topic, that's fine,feel free to close it. I just thought maybe since the shows have so much thematically or topically in common, that perhaps it was an easter egg or some common motif in in some genres of music or music pertaining to genres of cinema.

Comment: All I hear is The Story by Brandi Carlile. Listen when the string starts. Only S1 though, it's changed for S2 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only similarity between these two pieces is the use of piccolo or flute playing a plaintive melody in the high register. This is standard orchestral writing, and very common. See this example from Dmitri Shostakovich's 5th Symphony from 1937 which both composers would probably know well:

There is no evidence that one of these pieces was inspired by the other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just thought may it was little easter egg, but if there's no evidence, that's fine. I will wait a little bit to give others a chance to answer, but I will probably mark yours as the big answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's an Easter egg in reference to the flute song in the episode the inner light which is season 5, episode 25 of the next generation